# Error scraping Amazon Data with Python and BeautifulSoup

Tags: python, python-3.x, beautifulsoup, python-requests

I just started with Python and I have this strange behaviour that Python gives me an Error most of the time and sometimes it compiles my code correctly.

```py
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

jblCharge4URL = 'https://www.amazon.de/JBL-Charge-Bluetooth-Lautsprecher-Schwarz-integrierter/dp/B07HGHRYCY/ref=sr_1_2_sspa?__mk_de_DE=%C3%85M%C3%85%C5%BD%C3%95%C3%91&keywords=jbl+charge+4&qid=1562775856&s=gateway&sr=8-2-spons&psc=1'

def get_page(url):
    page = requests.get(url, headers=headers)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, 'html.parser')
    return soup

def get_product_name(url):
    soup = get_page(url)
    try:
        title = soup.find(id="productTitle").get_text()
        print("SUCCESS")
    except AttributeError:
        print("ERROR")
while(True)
    print(get_product_name(jblCharge4URL))
```

Console Output:

```
ERROR  
None  
ERROR  
None  
ERROR  
None  
ERROR  
None  
ERROR  
None  
ERROR  
None  
ERROR  
None  
ERROR  
None  
ERROR  
None  
ERROR  
None  
ERROR  
None  
ERROR  
None  
ERROR  
None  
ERROR  
None  
**SUCCESS**  
None  
ERROR  
None  
**SUCCESS**  
None  
ERROR  
None  
ERROR  
None  
ERROR  
None  
ERROR  
None  
ERROR  
None  
ERROR  
None
```

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I made a few adjustments to your code and this should get you back on the right track:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

jblCharge4URL = 'https://www.amazon.de/JBL-Charge-Bluetooth-Lautsprecher-Schwarz-      integrierter/dp/B07HGHRYCY/ref=sr_1_2_sspa?__mk_de_DE=%C3%85M%C3%85%C5%BD%C3%95%C3%91&  keywords=jbl+charge+4&qid=1562775856&s=gateway&sr=8-2-spons&psc=1'

def get_page(url):
    page = requests.get(url)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(page.text, 'html.parser')
    return soup

def get_product_name(url):
    soup = get_page(url)
    try:
        title = soup.find(id="productTitle")
        print("SUCCESS")

    except AttributeError:
        print("ERROR")
    return(title)   
print(get_product_name(jblCharge4URL))
```

Answer (score 0):

What `headers` are you using in `page = requests.get(url, headers=headers)` ?
You would want something that tricks the server into believing that you are a genuine user and not a script. I would recommend using something basic like

```
headers = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.3; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/54.0.2840.71 Safari/537.36'}
```

Also, you might want to print the value of variable `soup` in your exception as you debug this issue. Printing `soup` will give you the HTML of the page and you can then dig inside the source code to understand where the issue lies.

Answer (score 0):

Apart from using `requests` and `BeautifulSoup` combination, you could also use the [requests-html](https://github.com/kennethreitz/requests-html) package to download your web page and parse the content at the same time. An example of using requests-html would be:

```
from requests_html import HTMLSession

url = r"https://www.amazon.de/JBL-Charge-Bluetooth-Lautsprecher-Schwarz-integrierter/dp/B07HGHRYCY/"

req = HTMLSession().get(url)
product_title = req.html.find("#productTitle", first=True)
print(product_title.text)  #JBL Charge 4 Bluetooth-Lautsprecher in Schwarz – Wasserfeste, portable Boombox mit integrierter Powerbank – Mit nur einer Akku-Ladung bis zu 20 Stunden kabellos Musik streamen
```

Hope it helps.